# javascript window.open will not work on Chrome console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to test on Chrome console (F12):

```
window.open("www.stackoverflow.com");
```

But I just get:

```
undefined
```

Shouldn't it work here?

Comment: Is your pop-up blocker blocking it like [this](http://i.imgur.com/KiwO2kQ.png)?

Comment: That's what happens to me.

Comment: For me it is working. Try your pop-up blocker, because this is how most spam sites opens new content without your permission.

Comment: @RionWilliams yes! just saw it, it shows briefly only on first attempt. Is there a way to bypass it with javascript?

Comment: This is likely there for security purposes as the `window.open()` function generally *requires* user interaction of some kind in order to open one without being blocked (i.e. clicking a button, etc.)

Comment: @TomBrito I think you can't bypass this, at least from the console. Try doing that in your site script, inside some handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely a result of security measures taking over to protect the browser. Generally the [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) function requires some type of user interaction in order to be opened programatically (i.e. a button being clicked, etc.).

If no behavior like this occurs and the browser receives a `window.open()` request, the built-in pop-up blocker will likely handle it as it will assume something nefarious is afoot.

Answer (score 2):

Try the javascript protocol in the navigation bar.

In Chrome go to location where you type URL and type:

```
javascript:window.open("www.stackoverflow.com"); <ENTER>
```

It works!  A new window will open.

**Note**, if you copy/paste the text I typed, it'll try to protect you by not allowing it.

**Note 2**: If you change the domain it'll try to protect you from XSS (cross-site scripting).

Answer (score 1):

Your URL is for a file named `www.stackoverflow.com` in the same directory as the current web page. To indicate that it should use that as a server name, the name needs to be prefaced with `//`.

```
window.open('//www.stackoverflow.com');
```

Also, if the current page you're viewing is not from an HTTP server, you'll need the protocol scheme as well; otherwise, it will try to use the same protocol.

```
window.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
window.open("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
```

Ps. You are writing "windows" instead of "window".

**EDIT**

He wrote "windows" in the title and then edited it.

Comment: If he were writing `windows`, he would be getting an error, not a return value of `undefined`.

Comment: Sorry, he wrote "windows" in the question title.